# Access - Update table if value = any value from another table

Tags: database, ms-access, select, set

I`m trying to write simple query in **Access**. I would like to update "TableA" column IsVerified = 'Yes' if this record exist in another table. For example:

**TableA: Id | SerialNumber | IsVerified** 

1 | ABC | False 
2 | BCD | False 
3 | DDD | False

**TableB: Id | SerialNumber** 

1 | DDD 
2 | BCD 
3 | JJJ

**TableA after update:**

1 | ABC | False 
2 | BCD | True 
3 | DDD | True

Any here is my query:

```
UPDATE [TableA]
SET [IsVerified] = true
FROM ( SELECT SerialNumber FROM TableB) t2
WHERE t2.SerialNumber = [TableA].[SerialNumber]
```

I`m getting error that query syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want.

```
UPDATE TableB INNER JOIN TableA ON TableB.SerialNumber = TableA.SerialNumber SET TableA.IsVerified = "True"
WHERE (([TableA].[SerialNumber]=[TableB].[SerialNumber]));
```